# .NET Core 2.1 Edit cshtml causes error during debug

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

In one of my VS 2017 instance, the same solution would required a shut down and rebuild when editing a cshtml file during debug.  I have search google for a few days now and cannot find a solution.

This is the error:

An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Generated Code

The type 'PartialTagHelper' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

Comment: BTW: I don't have 2.1.1.0 referenced any where in the solution/project.

Comment: Can you share your .csproj file?

Comment: It could be a dependent assembly. If you have another package that depends on the higher version of ASP.NET Core, it will cause that to be pulled in. Check the dependencies of all your package references in all your projects.

Comment: Updated the SDK to latest version fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `NuGet` dependencies and dependencies of the dependencies to figure out which of them is dependent on version `2.1.0`.

As for fixing the issue there are the following **options**:

- Update all the `Microsoft.*` `NuGet`packages to `2.1.1` - should fix the
  problem.
- Or clean up the build outputs, `NuGet` cache, and delete .vs folder to
  avoid any `caching` issues and then - rebuild again. If won't help,
  get the repository sources to new directory from scratch.